# Leaves growing on a leaf of a Begonia

Tags: botany

I've a Begonia species. Somehow it started to grow new leaves on top and right in the center of an existing leaf which you can see in the center of the image. Why is it doing this? Apparently it is not a disease because the Begonia itself is growing fast. Will the new leaves eventually become a new Begonia which can survive on its own?

[image: A Begonia growing leaves on top of a leaf]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phenomenon you are observing is probably Adventitious buds. The plantlets can develop on intact leaves or on injured one.

Back to Begonia, this phenomenon usually occurs on injured leaves, so, probably, the plant was injured during movement/by insect or by other means and because of this started to create plantlets.

[image]

Comment: Will these plantlets eventually be able to survive on their own?

Comment: @wie5Ooma I think yes, definitely...

Answer (score 1):

[image] African Violet plantlet growing from another african violet leaf that I'm growing. This one is growing at the stem and leaf junction. I also have another leaf that has three plants starting to grow along the bottom edge of a leaf. If I remember from my high school days in horticulture class,(when I was in school with Moses), this probably occured when I cut and potted the leaf and scratched or rubbed the leaf thereby stimulating the cells and causing growth. The article before mine gives you the scientific version of this phenomenon.

Comment: Hi James. Welcome to [biology.se]. I want to point out that this post does not really answer the question; it is more like "I have this problem too". If at all it does answer the question to some extent, it is based on anecdotal evidences. Can you please cite a relevant source (perhaps a horticulture manual, book or a research article) to support your claim?